# Keyboard shortcut to select entire column in attributes table QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How can I select an entire column in the attributes table in QGIS? Ideally I would like to do it using a keyboard shortcut. In a search around the net I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to do with that column?

Comment: Copy and paste into either excel or a text file

Answer (score 3):

Make a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with SQL query:

```sql
select column
from table
```

Then you can select all attributes from the Virtual Layer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can select a single column. If you want to export a single column for copying into Excel or something then you have a couple options. You could select the entire table, copy, paste it into a spreadsheet, and the delete the unwanted columns. Or you could right click on the layer in the table of contents and click Export > Save Features As, then set the format to MS Office Open XML Spreadsheet and deselect all the columns/fields that you do not want to export.