# Automatically zoom to feature which is edited in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing, features, zoom

I want to edit many features in the attribute table, for which I have to see imagery in the background of the features. To speed the process up, ideally I do not want to use the mouse to click somewhere.

Right now I can edit a field, `tab` to jump to next field, edit, ...
When finished with the last attribute of a feature using `tab` will jump to the first attribute of the next feature (which is nice), but then I would like to pan/zoom to that feature (<kbd>Str</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>/ <kbd>Str</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) which is only possible if the entire line is selected.

So either I would like to know how to select a column in the attribute table with keyboard shortcut?

The question was asked in [Keyboard shortcut to select entire column in attributes table QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391163/keyboard-shortcut-to-select-entire-column-in-attributes-table-qgis) already, but my use case is different and I wonder if there is a way for that.

Or alternatively I would like to zoom to that feature automatically.

Comment: Please check my updated answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the script below to open your layer's attribute table with the behavior you describe temporarily implemented.

To run the script, open the Python console, open a new blank editor, paste in the script below, make sure the layer you are working on is the active layer in the TOC panel, then click the green 'Play' button to execute the script. The attribute table for your layer will be opened. Now, every time you tab from the last column of one row to the first cell of the next row, the canvas will zoom automatically to that feature.

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

att_tbl = iface.showAttributeTable(lyr)

tbl_view = att_tbl.findChildren(QTableView)[0]

sel_mod = tbl_view.selectionModel()
    
def row_changed(current, previous):
    feature_id = current.model().data(current, QgsAttributeTableModel.FeatureIdRole)
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFeatureIds(lyr, [feature_id])
    
sel_mod.currentRowChanged.connect(row_changed)
```

Quick & dirty demo which shows the expected behavior:

[image]

Comment: Will a person need some special imports ?

Comment: @Taras, thanks for testing! I used `zoomToFeatureIds()` which in theory should be reliable. It uses extent of bounding box of feature geometries (can be multiple and/or multi-part features). It should centre the canvas on the centre of the bounding box (it seems to work that way for me) :-\

Comment: @Taras, Kein Problem- Alles gut!

Comment: Wow!! Such a small world! :-)

Comment: Indeed, I would not be amazed, if we are neighbors with your relatives @_@

Comment: Thanks, that's working! Although it has the limitation that an id column exists, as you said. Further this column is not allowed to be hidden. And at project restart you have to run the script again. So it's great for now but might be worth to add as a function in future QGIS versions.

Comment: @jens wiesehahn, Good news- I have edited my answer. I only had to dig a little in the source code. With this method you do not need an 'id' column at all. You are right, it would probably be useful feature which I would be happy to develop. When I get time I will try to make a pull request to add this functionality to a future release.

Comment: I just testet to replace `zoomToFeatureIds()` by `panToFeatureIds()` to keep the scale when switching to the next feature and it also works. :)